# encoding problems with htmlespecialchars and htmlentities

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im having some trouble retrieving some info from my mysql database.

it stores that:

```
Comida Adultos:5&lt;br /&gt;Comida Ni&amp;ntilde;os:5
```

and when I make that in the browser:

```
html_entity_decode($bookings['booking_observation'])
```

all is right but when I try to set to a cell with PHPExcel I get that string:

```
Comida Adultos:10<br />Comida Ni&ntilde;os:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you use UTF-8 for all the strings that you set in PHPExcel

```
html_entity_decode($bookings['booking_observation'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Note that `<br />` has no special meaning in MS Excel, it's simply a series of characters, so you'll probably also want to do

```
str_replace('<br />', "\n", $value)
```